# Find elements in stl::set<object> based on member variable of object

Tags: c++, stl, set

I have tried searching for this but couldn't really find a proper answer. I have a stl::set of a custom class I made.

The class looks like

```
class myObject{

public:
  int a;
  int b;
  int c;

// constructor and operator < ()
}
```

The < comparison is based on `b` and `c` but I want to find elements in the set by `a`. Is there a way to do that other than performing a linear search by iterating over the set and checking for `myObject.a`? I am trying to get a sorted container of `myObject` but I need to be able to find elements in that container by the identifier `a` which is not really involved in the < comparison.

Comment: I'm afraid it's not possible.

Comment: You could maintain a separate index for lookup by `a`.

Comment: @KerrekSB - How would I do that? I would be inserting and removing values from the set all the time too. So this index would also have to be updated with every insert and remove. Thanks.

Comment: Yes, you'd have to keep the two in sync, so you'd insert each new item in both the set and the index (e.g., map) and when you remove from the set, you'd remove the corresponding item from the map as well.

Comment: Yes, quite. A separate multiset of iterators comes to mind. Or use a ready-made solution that does exactly that, such as boost.multiindex.

Comment: @JerryCoffin - Just out of curiosity, is there a way to avoid object duplication by using reference to the object in one of the containers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it using boost::multi_index_container

```
class myObject
{
public:
    int a;
    int b;
    int c;
    bool operator < (const myObject& obj) const
    { return b < obj.b; }
};

using namespace boost::multi_index;
typedef multi_index_container<
    myObject,
    indexed_by<
        ordered_unique<identity<myObject> >, // index by operator <
        ordered_unique<member<myObject, int, &myObject::a> > // index by member a
  > 
> SetOfmyObjects;

typedef SetOfmyObjects::nth_index<0>::type SetIndex_b;
typedef SetOfmyObjects::nth_index<1>::type SetIndex_a;
```

...

```
    SetOfmyObjects s;
    const SetIndex_b& index_b = s.get<0>();
    SetIndex_b::iterator it_b;
    for (it_b = index_b.begin(); it_b != index_b.end(); ++it_b)
        // ordered by b
    const SetIndex_a& index_a = s.get<1>();
    SetIndex_a::iterator it_a;
    for (it_a = index_a.begin(); it_a != index_a.end(); ++it_a)
        // ordered by a
```

Comment: I wasn't planning on using Boost at this point in my project but that is extremely convenient. I am going to use this. Thanks for the elaborate code as its going to save me a lot of research.

Comment: will this also preserve order of insertion for duplicates?

Comment: it won't even work for duplicates, since it uses `ordered_unique` index. You asked about a set and you can't have duplicates in a set. You may use `ordered_non_unique` index that'll allow for duplicates. I don't know if it's stable. It models std::multiset, stability of which is a rather moot point.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. I did ask about the set but I extended the conversation to multiset to include duplicates. I understand that std::multiset is stable only if you use C++11. I was wondering of boost has had that capability for a while. Thanks for the pointers though. I will try hunting for information in `ordered_non_unique`