# std::find Object by Member

Tags: c++, stl, find, member

## Scenario

I’ve run into a speedbump while using the STL with what seems like a normal scenario, simplified here:

```
class Person {
  string Name;
  int    Age;
};

vector<Person> people;
AddPeople(people);

string s("Bob");
find(people.begin(), people.end(), s);
```

## Problem

Unfortunately `find` wants to compare the entire class.

## Question

Is there a better or more appropriate way to do this the “STL way”? The suggested questions weren’t helpful, but I managed to find a couple of [related](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13202067/find-elements-in-stlsetobject-based-on-member-variable-of-object) [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13202067/find-elements-in-stlsetobject-based-on-member-variable-of-object) but no direct solution.

## Work-arounds/Tests

There’s some potential work-arounds:

1. Forgo `find` altogether (cluttered, but could be refactored):

   bool bBob = false;
   for (UINT i = 0; i < people.size(); i++) {
   if (people[i].Name == s)
   bBob = true;
   break;
   }
2. Provide conversion operator (implicit conversion doesn’t work; explicit can’t be used in `find`):

   class Person {
   string Name;
   int    Age;
   operator string() {return Name;}
   };

   Person b ("Bob", 99);
   string s ("Bob");
   b  == s;     //doesn’t work
   string(b) == s;     //works, but no good for find()
3. Define a standalone equality operator (simple, effective, but globally exposed):

   BOOL operator==(Person l, string r) {
   return l.Name == r;
   }
4. Define a member equality operator (makes comparison order dependent; object must be first):

   class Person {
   string Name;
   int    Age;
   bool operator==(string s) {return Name == s;}
   };

   Person b ("Bob", 99);
   string s ("Bob");
   b==s;               //works
   s==b;               //doesn’t work, but not a problem for find()

It looks like #4 is the best candidate, but none seem ideal or feel “STL”, and some have problems.

Answer (score 10):

> Is there a better or more appropriate way to do this the “STL way”?

You can use [`std::find_if`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/find) (powered by C++11 lambdas):

```
std::string name = "Bob";
// ...
std::find_if(std::begin(people), std::end(people), 
    [&] (Person const& p) { return p.Name == name; }
```

Notice, that calling it "STL way" is inappropriate. This is the C++ Standard Library, not the STL ("Standard Template Library"). The STL served as a strong inspiration for the Containers and Algorithms Library of the C++ Standard Library, but the two things are not the same. See [this Q&A on StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5205491/1932150) for further information.

**EDIT:**

Since you are using a compiler that does not support lambdas, you can define your own functor predicate:

```
struct person_has_name
{
    person_has_name(std::string const& n) : name(n) { }  
    bool operator () (Person const& p) { return p.Name == name; }
private:
    std::string name;
};
```

And use it with `std::find_if` this way:

```
std::string name = "Bob";
// ...
std::find_if(people.begin(), people.end(), person_has_name(name));
```

Comment: `You can use std::find_if (powered by C++11 lambdas).`   Hmm, I just dug out my copy of a C++ book and sure enough it does (briefly) mention `find_if`. I’ll look into that (hopefully VS2003 supports it). Thanks for the information about STL≠C++SL, I resisted STL for a long time and stuck to MFC, so I’m not familiar with the distinctions.

Comment: @Synetech: Unfortunately, VS2003 does not support it. You would need VS2010 at least. Otherwise, you can define your own functor

Comment: Ah, okay. I have a book from 2005 that mentions `find_if`, so I figured it was from C99; I’m fine with using it with a functor.

Comment: @Synetech: I updated the answer, this should work with VS2003

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of ways to do it, all involving some kind of callable objects and [`std::find_if`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/find).

The first is to use the new C++11 lambda:

```
std::find_if(people.begin(), people.end(), [](const Person& person)
    { return person.Name == "Bob"; });
```

---

If you have an older compiler that doesn't support lambdas, you could use a [functor object](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Function_object#In_C_and_C.2B.2B):

```
class FindPersonByName
{
    std::string name;

public:
    FindPersonByName(const std::string& name) : name(name) {}

    bool operator()(const Person& person) const
        { return person.Name == name; }
};

std::find_if(people.begin(), people.end(), FindPersonByName("Bob"));
```

---

Of course both of these requires your class to have the `Name` member public. But you can change it to use a public `GetName` function instead and add that to the class.

Comment: That looks promising. Using arrays (even simulated arrays) feels “old fashioned” and doesn’t fit the “container way”. I’ll give both a shot.

Comment: Isn’t there a way to use a callback instead of a lambda? Something like: `bool CompName(Person p, string s) {return p.Name==s;} … find_if(people.begin(), people.end(), "Bob", CompName);` Hmm, it looks like a [adapter might work](http://www.cplusplus.com/forum/beginner/393/#msg1301).

Comment: @Synetech The C++11 way is to use [`std::bind`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/bind), but since you seem to have an old compiler then one of the (now) deprecated [function adaptors](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional) would have to do.

Answer (score 1):

I guess you want these for subclasses or classes that share a property called name, if not you could create a simple function yourself. If you do want it to work for any class that has a property name you could create a template like this:

```
template < class ClassWithNameProperty >
ClassWithNameProperty * searchName (std::string name,
                                    std::vector<ClassWithNameProperty *> array)
{
    for (ClassWithNameProperty * obj: array)
    {
        if (obj.compare(obj->name))
        {
            return obj;
        }
    }
    return NULL;
}
```

Or however you want your search function to work, hope this helps you